# Let the navbar appear without spaces in between

Tags: html, css, navbar

Can someone explain me how i need to set the css statements to get the navbar one after another, without any free spaces?

Also it would be handy to know, how i can set the navbar over the whole display, that its automaticly working on different screen resolutions.

I tried finding a solution on w3schools.

```
<div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Compacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Coupes</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Sedans</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Sports</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Sports Classics</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Super</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Muscle</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Off-Road</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">SUVs</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Vans</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Industrial</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Commercial</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Utility</a></li>
                <li><a href="@" class="button">Motorcycles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

/* css */

.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline;
}

.navbar a {
    border: none;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active {
    background-color: #f0a041;
    color: #ffff00;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #f0a041;
    color: #ffff00;
}

tr, th {
    border: none;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the negative margin and your problem will get solved . 

Here is the snippet .

just change the css property of the following class .

```
.navbar li {
        display: inline;
        margin-right: -0.26rem;
    }
```

This will definitely solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Just add float: left to li.

```
.navbar li {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give ul a `display: flex`, and the a tags a `white-space pre`:

```css
/* css */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space:pre;
}

.button:active,
.button:hover {
  background-color: #f0a041;
  color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Compacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Coupes</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Sedans</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Sports</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Sports Classics</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Super</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Muscle</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Off-Road</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">SUVs</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Vans</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Industrial</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Commercial</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Utility</a></li>
    <li><a href="@" class="button">Motorcycles</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```